# Add a sequence to list SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript

I have a problem of sequence in the list SharePoint 2010. I need a column `Sequence` with format `000001`. This column is in type of single text.

I think the best way is customizing a workflow, but I cannot use SharePoint Designer, neither deploy a workflow as a WSP file.

I tried the column calculated who is equal to `ID`, but I must refresh the page to display the right number and the last number always `000000`.

I want to try JavaScript to set the value of column. But the code does not work in my site:

```
$("input[title='title_of_the_field']").val('0');
```

I find the JavaScript for updating a list item in the site Microsoft. But it does not work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using JavaScript. Steps

1. Open the NewForm page of the list. Example `http://webappurl/sitecollection/site/lists/listname/newform.aspx`
2. Click Site Actions and Edit Page
3. Add new web part -> Content Editor Web Part
4. [Edit HTML](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4988.sharepoint-2010-how-to-add-html-content-into-the-content-editor-webpart.aspx) and insert below code

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
       function pad(num, size) {
           var s = num+"";
           while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
           return s;
       }

       //CHANGE SITECOLLECTION URL
       var siteUrl = '/sitecollection/site';
       function retrieveListItems() {
           var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
           //CHANGE test TO THE ACTUAL LIST NAME
           var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('test');

           var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
           camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
           this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

           clientContext.load(collListItem);

           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed))
       }

       function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
           if(collListItem.get_count() == 0) {
               $('input[title^="Sequence"]').val('000001');
               return;
           }
           var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
           while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
               var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
               var maxId = oListItem.get_id();
               maxId = maxId + 1

               var nextSequence = pad(maxId, 6);

               $('input[title^="Sequence"]').val(nextSequence);
           }    
       }

       function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
       }

       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Hi Amal, thank you very much. I tried your script, but it does not work, there is no value in the column Sequence. And alert 'Request failed' does not appear.

Comment: Make sure the siteUrl and the listname are updated. Its most likely you have provided wrong siteURL.

Comment: I had changed site URL and listname

Comment: What is the exact error message. Inside `onQuerySucceeded` put an alert statement `alert(nextSequence);`

Comment: Hi, it works. Because I modified formula with InfoPath. When I created a new sandard list, it works. But the first item always no value in Sequence. And other items always display 000002 in Sequence.

Comment: If I add alert Inside **onQuerySucceeded**, error message is **undefined**

Comment: @Anna I have updated the code to handle empty list as well as fixed 000002 issue.

Comment: It works! It is exactly I need. How I can do perfect code like you?????? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anna Please mark as answer. Keep learning!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to bother you again. I have a problem of saving form. I choose unique values for Sequence. If 2 users open the form at the same time, and another users save it. The value of **ID** for seconde user is not correct. Its value is **ID+1**, but the value of Sequence is correct.

Comment: Since we are handling this using client side. There is no way to handle this situation. You need to look by creating a custom info path form or a custom webpart which can handle this.