# Set title to list item ID and then display to user after from input

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an induction system based on a custom list. I have renamed the Title field to Induction Number and have a workflow that then sets the Induction Number field to the list items ID number.
What I need is for this number to be presented to the user at the point of (or immediately after) the point of entry. How can I achieve this?

Note: if there is another way of achieving the same objective of presenting a unique ID number to the user then I would consider this too. Thanks

PS. I am using SP2010 Enterprise and SPD 2010. I'm not a developer.

Thanks

Comment: Check this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119419/add-a-sequence-to-list-sharepoint-2010 its about creating a Sequence number in advance.

Comment: Amal, It does not error but does nothing other than break my Managed Metadata columns